# Calculating Frames with SQL timecode

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a SQL table like below

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| Barcode |    Time1    |    Time2    | Frame for time 1 | Frame for time2 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
|       1 | 10:20:34.25 | 23:59:59.25 | NULL             | NULL            |
|         |             |             |                  |                 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

I want a way to calculate the frames for Time1 & Time2  like the following website does  http://www.zapstudio.net/framecalc/ in order to produce the table below

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
| Barcode |    Time1    |    Time2    | Frame for time 1 | Frame for time2 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
|       1 | 10:20:34.25 | 23:59:59.25 | 930880           | 2160000         |
|         |             |             |                  |                 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

However during the calculation of the frames, I want the frame rate for each bar code to be read from another table which is

```
+---------+--------+------------+
| Barcode | Format | Frame Rate |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       1 | 1080p  |         25 |
+---------+--------+------------+
```

Comment: You need to write your question so that no one needs to go to another website to understand it.  If that link ever goes dead, your question will be senseless.   What is the logic behind deriving the desired `frame` values from the `time` values you have?  Put it in your question itself.

Comment: You should roll back to my edit.   It is preferred on SO to present data as formatted text, rather than links to images.   You just made the question worse.

Comment: Also, it would be useful to know the names of the tables and the type of time columns to be able to give you precise answers.

Comment: Unless the logic to calculate `Frame for time 1` AND `Frame for time 2` is expensive to execute, I would encourage you to perform the calculations on the fly (as you need them), rather than storing the result in an actual column in the table.  For example, expose the data you need from a view, and have that view calculate and include both values.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple calculation once you understand the fact that you're frame rate is just the number of frames per second. You just need to convert your times to seconds and add the value after what seemed a decimal point but it's just additional frames.
The following calculation uses an implicit conversion to time, but it's limited to 23:59:59. If you need to have larger values, a more complex conversion can be set in place. It also doesn't account for incorrect format.

```
CREATE TABLE #Barcodes(
    Barcode         int,
    Time1           varchar(11),
    Time2           varchar(11),
    FramesForTime1  int,
    FramesForTime2  int
)
INSERT INTO #Barcodes(Barcode, Time1, Time2)
VALUES( 1, '10:20:34.25', '23:59:59.25')
CREATE TABLE #FrameRates(
    Barcode         int,
    Format          varchar(11),
    FrameRate       int
)
INSERT INTO #FrameRates VALUES( 1, '1080p', 25);

SELECT bc.Barcode, 
    bc.Time1,
    bc.Time2,
    DATEDIFF( ss, 0, LEFT( Time1, 8)) * Fr.FrameRate + RIGHT(Time1, 2) AS FramesForTime1, 
    DATEDIFF( ss, 0, LEFT( Time2, 8)) * Fr.FrameRate + RIGHT(Time2, 2) AS FramesForTime2,
    fr.Format,
    fr.FrameRate
FROM #Barcodes bc
JOIN #FrameRates fr ON bc.Barcode = fr.Barcode

GO
DROP TABLE #Barcodes, #FrameRates
```

I agree with the comment that suggests not storing these values. You could however, create computed columns that will be calculated on the fly when needed.

Answer (score 1):

The Mathematical formula would be: ([hours] * 3600 + [minutes] * 60 + [seconds]) * [frame_rate] + [miliseconds]

This is the code that update your table:

```
CREATE TABLE #FramesConfig
    (
        Barcode int,
        Format varchar(8),
        FrameRate int
    )

CREATE TABLE #Frames
(
    Barcode int,
    Time1 time(2),
    Time2 time(2),
    FrameForTime1 int,
    FrameForTime2 int
)

INSERT INTO #FramesConfig
VALUES(1, '1080p', 25)

INSERT INTO #Frames
VALUES (1, '10:20:34.25', '23:59:59.25', NULL, NULL)

UPDATE f
SET FrameForTime1 = DATEDIFF(SS, 0, f.Time1) * fc.FrameRate + RIGHT(f.Time1, 2),
FrameForTime2 = DATEDIFF(SS, 0, f.Time2) * fc.FrameRate + RIGHT(f.Time2, 2)
FROM #Frames f
    INNER JOIN #FramesConfig fc ON f.Barcode = fc.Barcode


SELECT *
FROM #Frames

DROP TABLE #Frames
DROP TABLE #FramesConfig
```